# MKMapView alloc initWithFrame crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm trying to add a map to my ViewController but it crashes on the init method. This is my code:

In TAMap.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface TAMap : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

In TAMap.m:

```
@implementation TAMap

@synthesize mapView = _mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Crashes here:
    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

I'm using ARC and my code seems to be entirely generic. I looked around and everywhere it's the same code for adding a map view. And yet it crashes with EXE_BAD_ACCESS. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code shown.  Are you sure it crashes on that specific line?  Put a breakpoint there and step through the code line by line.  How is TAMap created and presented?  What code is there in viewDidLoad after the initWithFrame?

Comment: Thanks, @AnnaKarenina. This is weird, I changed the location of the application folder on my mac and now the crash is gone. I have no idea what's going on but it looks like my problem is solved, sort of.

Answer (score 0):

My working code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
 [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```